# CSS cascade query

Tags: css

I have an external style sheet with

```
table {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

On one page I want to override the margin like this in the head of the document:

```
<style>
    table {
        margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
```

But it won't work unless I use `!important`.
Have I misunderstood the cascade?

Comment: Please [edit] to add the relevant parts of your HTML `<head>` section here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would probably help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that the order of your css and how specific it is does matter. If the style tag appears before the external css then you can't. unless important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `<style></style>` section is above the `<link href>` tag. try move the `<style>` section below the `<link>` and you won't need the `!important` anymore.

```
<head>
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
   <style>
     table { margin-top: 0px; }
   </style>
   ...
</head>
```

If you use some template engine with master layout inheritance.. make sure you inject the `<style>` block in your child template below the `<link href>` tag

_layout.html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

child.html:

```
{% block head %}
    <style type="text/css">
         table { margin-top: 0px; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Strike! You learn something every day - I didn't realise this, Thanks Vix

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to style the table inline, which will take precedence over anything else.

```
<table style="margin-top: 0px;">
```